# What is the proper way to handle a one-to-many Active Record association between a single model and one other model selected from a group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

Here's a basic diagram of the models I'm working with currently, and how I need them to be associated:

[image: data model diagram]

The models themselves are largely unimportant, but I'd like to be able to associate `Contracts` with one (and only one) other model (`Account`, `Location`, or `Region`). Business logic is similar but distinct depending on the association.

My first thought would be to take what might be a naïve approach, and to set up a foreign key on `Contract` for the associated model, and specify which model that foreign key points to using an enum.

Is there a recommended way to do this as far as architecture is concerned? Should I take a step back and consider what design decisions have caused me to ask this question in the first place?

I'm using Rails `5.2.2` and the latest version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a polymorphic association. You could apply similar methods dependent on contractable type.

Comment: My impression of polymorphic associations seems to be wrong, based on [this Rails guide page](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), it seems like this is what I'm looking for. I'll investigate further, thanks.